# can't access event data - event.data is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trigger an event "**modal:show**", where I pass the id of a modal object. But when I handle the event the *Event.data* are always undefined.

How should I access these values?

```
<img src="/GetPicture?pic=110&thumb=1" class="r img show-modal" data-modal="modalZoom" data-id="110" data-index="1" />

$(".show-modal").click(function (event) {
    var idModal = $(this).data("modal");

    event.preventDefault();

    $("#" + idModal).trigger("modal:show", [{ id: idModal }]);
});

$(".modal").on("modal:show", function (event) {
    var $modal = $("#" + event.data.id);

    $modalBlack.fadeIn("slow", function () {
        $modal.fadeIn("fast", function () {
            $modal.trigger("modal:visible", [{ id: event.data.id }]);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `data` isn't on the event object, it's on the DOM element.

Comment: @DanielBeck - the jQuery `data()` method is used to access the `dataset` of the DOM element.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes.  The DOM element. Not the event object.

Comment: @DanielBeck - `$(this)` inside the event handler is the jQuery Object referening the DOM element.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes.  And the bug is where they try to access that data on the event object instead (using `event.data.id` instead of `$(this).data("id")`).

Comment: So how should I access custom event data?

Comment: Wow - I'm focused on the first `click` handler not the `modal:show` handler - thanks for "opening my eyes"! Hey @TheRuler - you have an error in the `modal:show` handler.

Comment: You're right @gibberish, I have a bad habit of answering in comments, sorry. In progress

Comment: @gibberish to be fair basic errors/typos like this should just be close voted.

Comment: or provide an answer with some code so it's easy to see the solution for people like me

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan True, Rory, but I remember not that long ago being slightly confused myself as to where I should look for data. As I asked questions and had the answer pointed out, I learned. Those who teach should be rewarded, or what is the incentive to help beginners? To me at the time those were not basic errors. They were a result of a fundamental uncertainty of where to find things at that point in my understanding. So I suggest that this question is admittedly within a grey area, but on the legit side of a rewardable answer.

Comment: This isn't even a basic error / typo, it's a completely legit question about passing info between event handlers; I'm very sorry for the quick knee-jerk comment that dragged us all on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1):

The extra data you're trying to pass along with the `modal:show` event will not be attached to the event object itself; instead it would arrive as a second parameter to the event handler:

```js
$(".show-modal").click(function(event) {
  var idModal = $(this).data("modal");
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#" + idModal).trigger("modal:show", [{
    id: idModal
  }]);
});

$(".modal").on("modal:show", function(event, foo) {
  console.log(foo.id)  // <-- not event.data.id or event.id; the data you want isn't attached to the event object at all
  // ...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="show-modal" data-modal="modalZoom" data-id="110" data-index="1" />
<div class="modal" id="modalZoom">test</div>
```

In this particular case, though, since the ID you're looking for is on the same element on which the event was triggered, it would be much simpler to *not* pass the data between handlers,  but instead just read it from the DOM:

```js
$(".show-modal").click(function(event) {
  var idModal = $(this).data("modal");
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#" + idModal).trigger("modal:show");
});

$(".modal").on("modal:show", function(event) {
  console.log($(this).attr("id"))
  // ...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="show-modal" data-modal="modalZoom" data-id="110" data-index="1" />
<div class="modal" id="modalZoom">test</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

I replaced this:

```
var $modal = $("#" + event.data.id);
```

with this:

```
var $modal = $("#" + event.id);
```